# How to implicitly convert a std::vector of one type to another

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, stdvector, implicit-conversion

Is it possible to convert a vector of one type to another **implicitly**?

i.e some way to make this code work (obviously this is a simplified problem of what I am trying to do)

```
std::vector<int> intVec{1};

std::vector<double> doubleVec = intVec;
std::vector<double> doubleVec2;
doubleVec2 = intVec;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no conversion (implicit or otherwise) between different vector types.

You could initialise it from an iterator range:

```
std::vector<double> doubleVec(intVec.begin(), intVec.end());
```

perhaps wrapping this in a function:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To container_cast(From && from) {
    using std::begin; using std::end; // Koenig lookup enabled
    return To(begin(from), end(from));
}

auto doubleVec = container_cast<std::vector<double>>(intVec);
```

Comment: Thanks but that won't work for me. Basically I have a  huge code with type vector<pair<int,int>> and now instead of using vector<pair<int,int>>, i want to use  vector<myClass>. I know how to implicitly convert pair to myClass, but it becomes tricky when they are in a vector.

Comment: @death_relic0 If `myClass` is constructible from `pair<int, int>`, this will work. If it's not, then... well I don't know how you would expect anything to work.

Comment: @death_relic0: If the conversion from `pair` to `myClass` is implicit, then this will work. The range constructor will implicitly convert each element.

Comment: my bad, by "this wont work" I didn't mean the code was wrong, I meant that approach wasn't exactly what I was looking for. But thanks anyways. I guess "what I'm looking for" is not possible.

Comment: I Koenig'd your iterators, just because.  One thing to consider is if `from` is an rvalue, should we conditionally use move iterators to rip the guts out of each element if the move is noexcept?

Comment: @Yakk: If we were writing an ultrageneric library trying to cover all imaginable use cases, probably. If we're writing a simple helper for the OP's use case, probably not.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class T, class A=std::allocator<T>>
struct magic_vector:std::vector<T,A> {
  using base=std::vector<T,A>;
  using base::base;
  magic_vector(magic_vector const&)=default;
  magic_vector(magic_vector &&)=default;
  magic_vector& operator=(magic_vector const&)=default;
  magic_vector& operator=(magic_vector &&)=default;
  magic_vector()=default;

  template<class U, class B,
    class=typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U,T>::value>::type
  >
  magic_vector( magic_vector<U,B> const& o ):
    base( o.begin(), o.end() )
  {}
  template<class U, class B,
    class=typename std::enable_if<
      std::is_convertible<U,T>::value
      && noexcept( T(std::declval<U&&>()) )
    >::type
  >
  magic_vector( magic_vector<U,B>&& o ):
    base(
      std::make_move_iterator(o.begin()),
      std::make_move_iterator(o.end())
    )
  {}
};
```

`magic_vector`s are vectors that auto convert from other `magic_vector`s.

If you have a pointer to a `magic_vector` that you convert into a pointer to `vector`, then delete it as a `vector`, the result is undefined behavior.  (However in practice, there will be no harm in every C++ implementation I have checked).  This is, however, a strange way to act with `vector`s.

Replace use of `vector` with `magic_vector`.  So long as you don't have specializations on the exact type of a container in your code, it should be a drop-in replacement, except now it will auto-convert between them.

Work could be done to have `magic_vector`s auto-convert with `vector`s instead of just with `magic_vector`s.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a conversion function. It allows you to express intent at the call site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class To, class From, class Allocator>
std::vector<To, typename Allocator::template rebind<To>::other>
implicit_convert(const std::vector<From, Allocator>& vf)
{
    return { std::begin(vf), std::end(vf) };
}

template<class To, class ToA, class From, class FromA>
void implicit_overwrite(std::vector<To, ToA>& to, const std::vector<From, FromA>& from)
{
    to.clear();
    std::copy(begin(from), end(from), back_inserter(to));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    std::vector<int> vi { 1, 2 , 3 };
    auto vd = implicit_convert<double>(vi);

    cout << "after conversion\n";
    for (const auto& i : vd) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    vi.push_back(4);
    implicit_overwrite(vd, vi);
    cout << "after copy\n";
    for (const auto& i : vd) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
after conversion
1
2
3
after copy
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

you could go for something like this (assuming myclass is your class that can be constructed from a `std::pair`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class myclass
{
public:
    myclass(const std::pair<int, int>& p): first_(p.first), second_(p.second) {}
    int first() {return first_;}
    int second() {return second_;}
private:
    int first_;
    int second_;
};

template <class T>
class myvector : public std::vector<T> 
{
    using base = std::vector<T>;
    using base::base;
};

template<>
class myvector<myclass> : public std::vector<myclass>
{
public:
    myvector(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& vp):
std::vector<myclass>(vp.begin(), vp.end()) {}

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vp {{12,3}, {1, 7}};
    myvector<myclass> mm = vp;
    cout<<mm[0].first(); //prints 12

}
```

You inherit `myvector` from `std::vector` and then you specialize it for `myclass`. Alternatively you could define `myvector` in a namespace and access it as `mynamespace::vector<myclass>`