# How to map a list of Numpy matrices to a vector of Eigen matrices in Cython

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython, eigen3

I have a C++ function which I want to run from Python. For this I use Cython.
My C++ function relies heavily on Eigen matrices which I map to Python's Numpy matrices using Eigency.

I cannot get this to work for the case where I have a list of Numpy matrices.

---

**What does works (mapping a plain Numpy matrix to an Eigen matrix):**

I have a C++ function which in the header (Header.h) looks like:

```
float MyCppFunction(Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> &inputMatrix);
```

In my CythonFile.pyx file I have (and create the maps using Eigency as explained [here](https://pypi.org/project/eigency/1.4/)):

```
cdef extern from "Header.h":
    cdef void _MyCppFunction "MyCppFunction"(FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor] &)
```

and

```
def my_python_function(np.ndarray[ndim=2, dtype=np.float32_t] my_matrix)
    return _MyCppFunction(FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor](my_matrix))
```

I can build this module using Cython and call `my_python_function` successfully from Python.

---

**What does not work (mapping a list of Numpy matrices to a vector of Eigen matrices):**

Now I try to do the same thing, but for a list of matrices. I cannot get this to work.
What I have:

The C++ function in the header (Header.h) looks like:

```
float MyCppFunction(std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>> &inputMatrixList);
```

In my CythonFile.pyx file I have:

```
cdef extern from "Header.h":
    cdef void _MyCppFunction "MyCppFunction"(vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] &)
```

and

```
def my_python_function(list my_matrix_list)
    cdef vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] map
    
    for matrix in my_matrix_list:
        map.push_back(FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor](matrix))
        
   return _MyCppFunction(map)
```

This won't compile unfortunately.

This concept does compile and run when I, for example, simply use a `list` of `int` which I want to map to a `std::vector<int>`. It does not work however, when I map a list of Numpy-matrices to a vector of Eigen matrices (which is the case I have denoted above).

---

**The Error I get:**

The error I get during compilation:
`error C2664: 'float MyCppFunction(std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>,std::allocator<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>>> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix,float,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1>,std::allocator<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix,float,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1>>>' to 'std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>,std::allocator<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>>> &' ./Header.h(21): note: see declaration of 'MyCppFunction'`

---

**My analysis so far:**

This works as expected, so: I can assign a python `list` of `int` to a C++ `std::vector<int>`.

This works also as expected, so: I can assign a variable of type `eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix,float,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1>` to a variable of type `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>`.

When I wrap the latter two variables in a list/vector, then I cannot assign this variables:
`std::vector<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix,float,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1>, std::allocator<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix,float,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1>>>` to a variable of type `std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>, std::allocator<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>>>`.

Maybe it has to do with the allocator part but I don't know since I'm not really a C++ expert.
Does anybody has a solution to map a list of Numpy matrices to a vector of Eigen matrices? Preferably, following the same patterns as above but other solutions are also welcome.

---

**My source code to reproduce:**

Below the source code I use to test. It has a function accepting a plain Eigen/Numpy matrix, and a function accepting a Vector/List of Eigen/Numpy matrices.

The code compiles if you comment out all passages of the vector variants. Else, I get a compile error. The (first) compile error I get when compiling is: `.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(16): error C2065: 'FlattenedMapWithOrder': undeclared identifier`.

I use the Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler (MSVC) 2019 on Windows. I also use Eigen version 3.4.0-rc1 in case it is relevant.

*cython_source.pyx*

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.cpp


from eigency.core cimport *  # Docs: https://pypi.org/project/eigency/1.4/
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import numpy as np

cimport numpy
cdef extern from "source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h":
    cdef float _MyCppFunction "MyCppFunction"(
                FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor] &
                )

    cdef float _MyCppFunctionVector "MyCppFunctionVector"(
                vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] &
                )


def my_python_function(np.ndarray[ndim=2, dtype=np.float32_t] my_matrix):
    cdef FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor] my_matrix_cpp

    my_matrix_cpp = FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor](my_matrix)

    return _MyCppFunction(my_matrix_cpp)


def my_python_function_vector(list my_matrix_list):
    cdef vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] matrix_map_vec
    cdef FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor] my_matrix_cpp

    for my_matrix in my_matrix_list:
        my_matrix_cpp = FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor](my_matrix)
        matrix_map_vec.push_back(my_matrix_cpp)

    return _MyCppFunctionVector(matrix_map_vec)
```

*cpp_source_cpp.h*

```
#pragma once
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Core>

#include <vector>
#include <numpy/ndarraytypes.h>
#include <complex>
typedef ::std::complex< double > __pyx_t_double_complex;
typedef ::std::complex< float > __pyx_t_float_complex;
#include "eigency_cpp.h"

float MyCppFunction(
    const Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>& inputMatrix
    );

float MyCppFunctionVector(
    const std::vector<FlattenedMapWithOrder<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>>& inputMatrixList
    );
```

*cpp_source_cpp.cpp*

```
#include "cpp_source_cpp.h"

float MyCppFunction(
    const Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>& inputMatrix
    )
{
//    std::vector<FlattenedMapWithOrder<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>> test;
    return 5.0;
}

float MyCppFunctionVector(
    const std::vector<FlattenedMapWithOrder<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>>& inputMatrixList
    )
{
    //Convert FlattenedMap to Eigen-Map.
    std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> convertedMatrixList(
                                                                                                            inputMatrixList.begin(), inputMatrixList.end() );
    return 6.0;
}
```

The relevant passages from my cython setup file, *setup_cython_module.py* are:

```
# Some constants
SOURCE_FOLDER_NAME = "source_cpp_cython"
OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "cython_module"

# Build extensions list
extensions = [
    Extension(f"{OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME}.{OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME}",
              [f"{SOURCE_FOLDER_NAME}/cython_source.pyx"],
              include_dirs=["."] + [f"{SOURCE_FOLDER_NAME}"]
                           + [f"{SOURCE_FOLDER_NAME}\Eigen"] + eigency.get_includes(include_eigen=False)
                           + [numpy.get_include()],
              language='c++',
              # extra_compile_args=['/MT'],  # To let the Microsoft compiler use a specific lib for threading required by OpenCV.
              )
    ]

# Build cython package
dist = setup(
    name=f"{OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME}",
    version="1.0",
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, language_level="3"),  # , gdb_debug=True),
    packages=[f"{OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME}"]
    )
```

*The full log output from Cython:*

```
Created output directory:  D:\Default_Folders\Documents\Development\RepoStefan\CythonTest\cython_module

running build_ext
building 'cython_module.cython_module' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\cenv38rl\lib\site-packages\eigency -I. -Isource_cpp_cython -Isource_cpp_cython\Eigen -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\cenv38rl\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\cenv38rl\include -IC:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\cenv38rl\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsource_cpp_cython/cython_source.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\source_cpp_cython/cython_source.obj /MT
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
cython_source.cpp
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\cenv38rl\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(17): error C2065: 'FlattenedMapWithOrder': undeclared identifier
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(17): error C2275: 'Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>': illegal use of this type as an expression
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(17): note: see declaration of 'Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1,-1,-1>'
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(17): error C2974: 'std::vector': invalid template argument for '_Ty', type expected
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\vector(443): note: see declaration of 'std::vector'
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(17): error C2976: 'std::vector': too few template arguments
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\vector(443): note: see declaration of 'std::vector'
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(17): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '>'
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(17): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(18): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
source_cpp_cython/cython_source.cpp(1964): error C2664: 'float MyCppFunctionVector(const std::vector)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix,float,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1>,std::allocator<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix,float,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1>>>' to 'const std::vector'
source_cpp_cython/cython_source.cpp(1964): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(16): note: see declaration of 'MyCppFunctionVector'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: That is your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30508404/5769463, it works without vector because of this line: https://github.com/wouterboomsma/eigency/blob/98019af331c2838018b86fe35c1f67de28736fb4/eigency/eigency_cpp.h#L394

Comment: Thanks, that seem indeed the core of my problem. Do you have any suggestion how I could make it work in my case? Eigency is the glue of my Python / C++ barrier. Should I extent Eigency's functionality with stuff from the post you mention? Or is their some other way to do this just in my project?

Comment: The lines from error message and your example don’t match. But basically cpp_source_cpp.h defines FlattenedMapWithOrder, if it does not as the error message suggests (do you really include the right one?) I’m afraid I cannot help you.

Comment: @ead, The code above is the actual code I use to reproduce this and reproduce the error message. Thank you for your help so far and I understand if this is it.
I spotted a mistake in your answer which is also in the code above, the `std::vector<FlattenedMapWithOrder<Eigen::Matrix, float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>` has one missing `<` brackets between Matrix and float? If you still have the patience, I can update the code and error log above.

Comment: Error says `.\source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h(16)` but 16th line in cpp_source_cpp.h is empty, so it cannot be the same file you are using. As I said, the compiler doesn't know `FlattenedMapWithOrder` (only the first error is important, everything after that might be just the result of the first one), but should if eigency_cpp.h were included.

Comment: Hi ead, I'm so sorry for the confusion. I sometimes add/remove some enters during debugging. That is why the line number in the *.h file does not match. I have updated the error log and code files (to include the thing about the missing `<`). Now the error is about `cpp_source_cpp.h(17)` which is the before last line. Now everything above should be consistent. Any idea how to make the compiler know what `FlattenedMapWithOrder` is, or how to change my declaration so the compiler understands how to match it with one of the existing declaration inside `eigency_cpp.h`?

Comment: FlattenedMapWithOrder doesn't exist in C++, only in Cython: https://github.com/wouterboomsma/eigency/blob/98019af331c2838018b86fe35c1f67de28736fb4/eigency/core.pxd#L353 you need to call it `eigency::FlattenedMap` in c++ part.

Comment: @ead, IT WORKS :). Thank you very much for your persistence. Because of the frustration I forgot the simplest things. Off course, I needed to use the namespace `eigency`, and I should have checked in the header that `FlattenedMapWithOrder` is `FlattenedMap` in C++. Anyway, I see you removed your answer. Do you want to place it back? I can upvote and accept it. Then I will edit it with the few details that made it work. You actually solved the tricky things. It may help others.

Comment: never mind. Feel free to add your own answer if you think it could be useful to somebody. My answer wasn't correct and never should have been created.

Comment: @ead, Your answer was quite excellent. Without your answer I would not been able to get it working. I also grasped the essence of the problemen en solution angle from it. Your answer just contained a few typo's which should have been easy to spot for someone who is much more comfortable in C++ then me. With all you hints, I was finally able spot them. I can edit to you answer so it becomes correct. It's fine if you don't want to, then I make my own to help others. If I make the answer, useful explanation will be lost though, e.g. about how to include `eigency_cpp.h` without the compile errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ead I found a solution.

`FlattenedMapWithOrder` has implementation so it can be assinged to an `Eigen::Matrix`.
However, `std::vector` does not have such functionality and since `std::vector<FlattenedMapWithOrder>` and `std::vector<Eigen::Matrix>` are of a different type, they cannot be assigned to one another.
More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508404/implicit-conversion-of-vector-from-one-type-to-another-c).
The implementation in `FlattenedMapWithOrder` mentioned above is [here](https://github.com/wouterboomsma/eigency/blob/98019af331c2838018b86fe35c1f67de28736fb4/eigency/eigency_cpp.h#L394).

To solve this, the function in the C++ code called from Cython need to simply have as input argument the matching type: `std::vector<FlattenedMapWithOrder>`.
To do this, the C++ code needs to know the definition of type `FlattenedMapWithOrder`.

To do this, you need to `#include "eigency_cpp.h"`. Unfortunately, this header is not self contained.
Therefore, (credits to @ead) I added these lines:

```
#include <numpy/ndarraytypes.h>
#include <complex>
typedef ::std::complex< double > __pyx_t_double_complex;
typedef ::std::complex< float > __pyx_t_float_complex;
#include "eigency_cpp.h"
```

Using this, I was able to declare this function in my C++ code:

```
void MyCppFunctionVector(
    const std::vector<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix, float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>& inputMatrixList,
    std::vector<eigency::FlattenedMap<Eigen::Matrix, float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>& outputMatrixList
    );
```

My *.pxy file looks like:

```
cdef extern from "source_cpp_cython/cpp_source_cpp.h":
    cdef void _MyCppFunctionVector "MyCppFunctionVector"(
                vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] &,
                vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] &
                )
                
                
def my_python_function_vector(
        list my_matrix_list_input,
        list my_matrix_list_output
    ):
    cdef vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] matrix_map_vec_input
    cdef FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor] my_matrix_input_cpp
    cdef vector[FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor]] matrix_map_vec_output
    cdef FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor] my_matrix_output_cpp

    # Convert input matrix to C++ type.
    for my_matrix_input in my_matrix_list_input:
        my_matrix_input_cpp = FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor](my_matrix_input)
        matrix_map_vec_input.push_back(my_matrix_input_cpp)

    for my_matrix_output in my_matrix_list_output:
        my_matrix_output_cpp = FlattenedMapWithOrder[Matrix, float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor](my_matrix_output)
        matrix_map_vec_output.push_back(my_matrix_output_cpp)

    # Call the C++ function.
    _MyCppFunctionVector(matrix_map_vec_input, matrix_map_vec_output)
    return my_matrix_list_output
```

That was it.